# Jquery Showcase how not to return to the first item on finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of images being shown using JQuery Showcase. Everythin works just fine except one thing - I need it continue sliding when after it shows last item - so it keeps going from right to left showing the first item etc after last item shown. Now it visualizes all the previous items sliding them from left to right to the first item and then starting from the beginning. Is there a way to make it work like a carousel?

Answer (score 0):

You should link to the specific plugin you're using - I found a couple with that name. It's likely that you should be looking for a new plugin, although it's possible the one you have could be modified.

Comment: This is a plugin from http://plugins.jquery.com/project/showcase. Version is the latest - 2.
Thanks.